# Login and logout not validated

Tags: android

I'm using android studio on making my first application, I have made login/logout with Google or Facebook, but the problem is when after I've logged in and if I press the back button, it goes back to the previous activity where I need to login again. Same goes after I've logged out, and if I press the back button, it goes back to the previous activity where I have logged in even if already logged out?

Is there something wrong with my code?

**Login_Activity.java**

`

```
    public class CustomerLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button googleBtn, fbBtn;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;


    GoogleSignInClient gsc;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    private String TAG = "CustomerLogin";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_login);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                        startActivity(new Intent(CustomerLogin.this, Dashboard_buy.class));
                        finish();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });

       
        googleBtn = findViewById(R.id.googleBtn);
        fbBtn = findViewById(R.id.fbBtn)
        googleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.googleBtn);
        fbBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbBtn);



        

        
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        gsc = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);


        googleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signin();
            }
        });


        fbBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(CustomerLogin.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
            }
        });
    }


    private void signin() {
        Intent intent = gsc.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 100) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                login();
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }


    private void login() {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

`

(After logging in, it will direct the user to Dashboard and in the dashboard, there's an account fragment)

**Account_Fragment.java**
`

```
    public class Account_fragment extends Fragment {
    private Button logoutGoogleBtn, logoutGoogleBtn;
    GoogleSignInClient gsc;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    TextView name, mail;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Account");

        name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        mail = v.findViewById(R.id.mail);



        logoutGoogleBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.logoutGoogleBtn);
        logoutGoogleBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.logoutGoogleBtn);

        logoutGoogleBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.logoutGoogleBtn);
        logoutGoogleBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.logoutGoogleBtn);



        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        gsc = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getContext(),gso);

        GoogleSignInAccount acc = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext());
        if (acc!=null){
            String Name = acc.getDisplayName();
            String Mail = acc.getEmail();
            name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            logoutbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            logoutfb.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            name.setText(Name);
            mail.setText(Mail);


        logoutbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SignOut();
            }
        });
    }



        logoutfb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),CustomerLogin.class));
                try {
                    finalize();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    private void SignOut() {

        gsc.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                try {
                    finalize();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),CustomerLogin.class));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

`

Comment: After `startActivity(this,Login_Activity.class)` use `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put intent flags, see more [here](https://androiddvlpr.com/android-intent-flags-everything-you-need-to-know/)

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

for example

```
private void login() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciated man.